# MySql Very Slow Writes & Out of memory error

Tags: mysql, memory, amazon-rds, performance, parameter, slow-log

I am having a rds db instance in AWS which is used by Drupal 7 instatllation.
I am getting the below error messages in the log:

```
> 130912 11:57:39 [ERROR] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: Out of memory
> (Needed 26843536 bytes) 130912 11:57:39 [ERROR]
> /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 26843536 bytes)
> 130912 12:35:47 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table
> m1newdb/cache_image InnoDB: because the .ibd file is missing. For
> help, please refer to InnoDB:
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
```

And another error like this:

```
> /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.31-log (Source distribution).
> started with: Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock Time Id
> Command Argument /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.31-log
> (Source distribution). started with: Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket:
> /tmp/mysql.sock Time Id Command Argument /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld,
> Version: 5.5.31-log (Source distribution). started with: Tcp port:
> 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock Time Id Command Argument
> /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.31-log (Source distribution).
> started with: Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock Time Id
> Command Argument /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.31-log
> (Source distribution). started with: Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket:
> /tmp/mysql.sock Time Id Command Argument
```

**My parameter that is set is as per below:**

```
default_storage_engine  = innoDb
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size  =  52428800
innodb_io_capacity = 10000
innodb_open_files = 120
max_allowed_packet = 33554432
max_connections = 3000
max_heap_table_size = 134217728
query_cache_size = 2147483648
read_buffer_size = 52428800
slow_query_log = 1
tmp_table_size = 134217728 
binlog_cache_size  =  32768
innodb_buffer_pool_size  = {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_io_capacity = 10000
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8388608
innodb_log_file_size  =  134217728
key_buffer_size      = 16777216
log_output  =  TABLE
max_binlog_size  =  134217728
read_rnd_buffer_size  =  524288
thread_stack =  262144
read_only = {TrueIfReplica}
```

**The site loads fast, but adding one article takes more than 2 minutes rendering the site unusable.**

**Instant Size:**

> M1.Medium.
>   HDD Size: 10GB
>   Memory : 4 GB
>   CPU : 2 Compute Unit`